# read and write data simultaneously in an existing file in java

Tags: java

How to read from an existing file and if contains a specific string ..i would like to delete that line from that file.how to do that in java??  if a file contains :

```
111
222
333
```

and if i take input 222 it will delete 222 and the file will be like:

```
111
333
```

code:

```
File ef = new File("Employee_info.txt");
       File tf = new File("temp.txt");  
       FileReader fr = new FileReader(ef);  
       BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(fr);  
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tf);  
       BufferedWriter bw =new BufferedWriter(fw);  
       String line;  
       while((line=br.readLine())!=null)  
        {  
            if(line.contains(del_id)) continue;  

            bw.write(line);  
            bw.newLine();  
        }  
        bw.close();  
        fw.close();  
        br.close();  
        fr.close();`
```

Comment: This looks quite straightforward, so it's hard to know what exactly where you are running into problems. Can you add your current code? [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

you typically have to read the whole file and then write the whole file, typically, for safety write to a temporary file, then when done delete the original and rename the temp file to the original name.

Comment: That's what i tried to do..but i can't rename the temp file or delete the previous file :/

Comment: @RealSazzad if you tried something, post it, don't expect us to write your code for you.

Comment: @EricDarchis i have tried and i have posted it above..can you please help me now??

Comment: delete the old file, then rename the new one